# SQL % is retrieved as [%] in DataTable of C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, datatable

I am retrieving data from SQL Server to a `DataTable` in C#. I have a `%` symbol in a SQL Server cell but in the `DataTable`, it is converted to a `[%]`. But I need the `%` symbol as it is in the `DataTable` as well.

I have a column `Unit` in my database table in which `%` is a record.

SQL query :

```
select Unit 
from UnitsTable 
where id = 654
```

I have stored it in dataTable. When I retrieve that record from the `DataTable` with the following code, I am getting like this `[%]`.

C# code :

```
dtTable.Rows[index]["Unit"]
```

Comment: I am not competent in C#, but I wanted to drag your attention to the fact that `%` is a special symbol in SQL (in LIKE clauses) - at the same time the way to escape special symbols is enclosing in `[]` - so my pure guess is that it might be done somewhere on C# level on purpose (i.e. to enable usage in LIKE clauses).

Comment: Ya but I need a way to prevent escaping it.